# onClick, onSubmit event not working in custom magnific popup component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, magnific-popup

In the magnific popup I have added a button with add to cart feature, whenever I attach onClick event from reactjs it doesn't trigger, but it does with jquery document click event but that is not good and also doesn't fetch for form data properly.

```
class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            product_id: this.props.product_id
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let that = this;
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#modal-dialog'
            },
            type: 'inline',
            fixedContentPos: true,
            fixedBgPos: true,
            overflowY: 'auto',
            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,
            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
            callbacks: {
                close: function() {
                    // that.closePopup();
                    that.props.closePopup();
                },
                open: function() {
                    $(document).on('click', '#addToCart', function() {
                        // This works but form data is empty
                        /*
                        let id = $(this).data('id');
                        that.handleSubmit(id);
                        */
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }


    handleSubmit(id) {
        let form = document.getElementById('product_' + id);
        let formData = new FormData(form);
        console.log(formData);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="modal-dialog" className="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
                <form name="form" id={'product_' + this.state.product_id}>
                    <div className="small-dialog-header">
                        <h3>{this.state.title}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer">
                        <div className="row small-gutters">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <input onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(this.state.product_id)} data-id={this.state.product_id} id="addToCart" type="button" value="Add to cart" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Is there a way to **attach reactjs event in magnificpopup open event**?